# Send CUSTOM variable to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am implementing Recurring Express checkout. The code for creating a profile is working. What I want to do now is pass it a custom value.

We can pass

> [DoExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

and

> [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

using the the following name

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM
```

I want to do the same for [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) so that I can access it in IPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRPP does not include the custom parameter like other API requests do, however, it does include the PROFILEREFERENCE parameter, which is meant to be treated like an invoice ID.  Whatever value you pass here would come back in IPN as rp_invoice_id.

So what you can do is save a local invoice record in your DB that includes any related data you need, and then pass that ID in the profilereference parameter of your CRPP request.  Then within your IPN script you pull this value from rp_invoice_id, and then pull any extra details you need about that invoice from your database using that ID value.

Here's a sample of an IPN that includes the rp_invoice_id.

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 6.45
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [next_payment_date] => 02:00:00 Feb 12, 2015 PST
    [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_id] => Q33PGJHM6K38Q
    [address_street] => 375 HWY 21 n
    [payment_date] => 02:12:06 Jan 12, 2015 PST
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [rp_invoice_id] => 1935
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-FWEAAAAXPVJ
    [address_zip] => 72616
    [first_name] => Tester
    [mc_fee] => 0.44
    [address_country_code] => US
    [address_name] => KARShop
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [amount_per_cycle] => 6.45
    [payer_status] => verified
    [currency_code] => USD
    [business] => payments@domain.com
    [address_country] => United States
    [address_city] => Berryville
    [verify_sign] => AtjWedapewmudDbf6C3S0..Z.7glAyXhJISOoiYcafN1Zb.VrOX7O8VH
    [payer_email] => tester@gmail.com
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [profile_status] => Active
    [amount] => 6.45
    [txn_id] => 5G2211475Y5810638
    [payment_type] => instant
    [payer_business_name] => Testers, LLC
    [last_name] => Testerson
    [address_state] => AR
    [receiver_email] => payments@domain.com
    [payment_fee] => 0.44
    [receiver_id] => M5VRAQYEFCSK6
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [residence_country] => US
    [transaction_subject] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [payment_gross] => 6.45
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [product_type] => 1
    [time_created] => 14:56:25 Apr 12, 2011 PDT
    [ipn_track_id] => 9318cc3589f1b
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working. I still can't understand why paypal has omitted support of custom variable for CRPP. Every other api call of there supports it except for this.

Comment: Yes, there is such a field as rp_invoice_id.  If you're not getting it in your IPN then you must not be including the PROFILEREFERENCE parameter in your CRPP request.  I've updated the answer with a sample of an IPN that includes it.